# Can't return a struct from a function in C

Tags: c, function, struct, return

Every time i read the employ.sex the program crashes, no errors, i can't find why this is happening. I'm very new at C. Is something wrong with "return pin[i]? Please help, i can't find anything in my search for it. Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

struct stoixeia
    {
        int age;
        float h;
        char sex;
    };
struct melos
    {
        char fname[50];
        char lname[50];
        int mnum;
        struct stoixeia employ;
    };

struct melos diavasma(int );

int main()
{
    struct melos pin[N];
    struct melos * ptr;
    int i,pli;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        pin[i]=diavasma(i);
        printf("%d", pin[i].mnum); // i just use this to see if it returns anything
    }
    return 0;
}

struct melos diavasma(int i)
    {
        struct melos pin[i];
        struct stoixeia employ;
        printf("Dose onoma\n");
        scanf("%s", pin[i].fname);
        printf("Dose epitheto\n");
        scanf("%s", pin[i].lname);
        printf("Dose arithmo mitroou\n");
        scanf("%d", &pin[i].mnum);
        printf("Dose ilikia\n");
        scanf("%d", &pin[i].employ.age);
        printf("Dose upsos\n");
        scanf("%f", &pin[i].employ.h);
        printf("Dose fulo\n");
        scanf(" %c", &pin[i].employ.sex);
        return pin[i];
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you added the C++ tag?

Comment: no, it was in the recommend it section, so i just added it

Comment: It certainly is not recommended to add tag for a **different** language. The pop-up just shows matches as you type - otherwise you would have added C#, too. Read the descrition of the tags.

Comment: sorry it's my first time using this website, won't happen again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close: rather than declaring an array, in which you use a single element past the end, hence the crash, declare a single struct:

```
struct melos diavasma(int i)
{
    struct melos pin;
    printf("Dose onoma\n");
    scanf("%s", pin.fname);
    printf("Dose epitheto\n");
    scanf("%s", pin.lname);
    printf("Dose arithmo mitroou\n");
    scanf("%d", &pin.mnum);
    printf("Dose ilikia\n");
    scanf("%d", &pin.employ.age);
    printf("Dose upsos\n");
    scanf("%f", &pin.employ.h);
    printf("Dose fulo\n");
    scanf(" %c", &pin.employ.sex);
    return pin;
}
```

Note that passing i is redundant now. Unless you plan to use it in a prompt, consider removing it from the function's parameter list.

Comment: that was it! thank you, was i trying to add an array of structs inside an array? it's my first time with structs and i'm still confused